# Eclipse - New Gradle project with Spock and Groovy

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle, build.gradle, spock

I am creating a **new Gradle Project** in Eclipse.
[image: New Gradle Project in Eclipse]

A new project with the following **structure** is created:
[image]

Because I dont need the folders `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` I **delete** them and I also **refactor->rename** the folders `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` into `src/main/groovy` and `src/test/groovy`. Leaving me with a structure like this:
[image]

Then I **convert** the project **to** a **Groovy project** doing the following by **rightclicking** the project:
[image]

Now I begin to edit my `build.gradle` file, which at the beginning looks as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

Since I want to use **Groovy**, I add:

1. `apply plugin: 'groovy'` at the beginning of the file
2. `compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3'` into `dependencies{...}`

Then I **click build**, which finishes **successfully**, but notifies me of a warning:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      build
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovywarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
1 warning

:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovywarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
1 warning

:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.496 secs
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Build finished succesfully!
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 2 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

To get rid of this **warning** I edit again `build.gradle` change 
 `sourceCompatibility = 1.5` to `sourceCompatibility = 1.7`
 and a **successive build** does not produce the aforementioned warning anymore.

Since I want to use **Spock**-Testing, I open `build.gradle` and add the following to it under `dependencies {...}`:

```
testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4"
```

Again I do a **build** and it again finishes **successfully**.

Now I want to start coding and therefore I add **new files**:

1. `Person2.groovy` to `src/main/groovy`
2. `Person2Test.groovy` to `src/test/groovy`

`Person2Test.groovy` looks like this:

```
package org.gradle
import spock.lang.Specification 
class Person2Test {
}
```

`Person2Test.groovy` shows the following error:
`Groovy:unable to resolve class spock.lang.Specification`

---

I am confused here. I added **Spock** to `build.gradle`, what else do I need to change in order to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was very simple, but also very subtle:

I had to right-click on the project and do a Refresh all for Gradle:

[image]